# How to make a migration file as already run?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I created a column in the database without creating the migration file.
Now i want to create a migration file for that column.How can i make the migration file as already run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails knows whether a migration has run based on finding the migration's ID in the `schema_migrations` table.

Run `rails db` to spin up your SQL front-end, and then

```
insert into schema_migrations(id) values (<leading digits of migration>);
```